# Name on ticket P&O ferry Hull to Rotterdam

Tags: passports, tickets, ferries

My friend just booked some tickets for a mini cruise from Hull, UK to Rotterdam, Netherlands. He used the short version of my name on the booking 'Sam' instead of my real name 'Samuel' which is on my passport. Will the booking need to be amended to match my passport? Had a quick look on their website and can't find anything.

**Seen as though I can't answer my own question as it's marked as duplicate(wrongly)**

This was marked as a duplicate, but the answer in the question it was similar to was about flying and stated you needed the correct name. P&O didn't care in the end, they didn't even question it. Not sure if that was their mistake or its procedure to shortened names.

If the name is completely wrong its a £15 fee to change at check in.

Comment: Maybe yes, maybe no. Why don't you ask the cruise company?

Comment: @Neusser, I will was just seeing if anyone had any experience as its sometimes an instant reply here

Comment: I agree with the reopen votes, passports for flying and for ferries are not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

So I went on the ferry without telling them about the name mistake.

P&O didn't care in the end, they didn't even question it. Not sure if that was their mistake or it's procedure for shortened names. We went as a big group so they didn't really look hard at passports, I was the one at the front sorting out the check-in though so they looked at mine more than anyone else's. My boarding ticket just said my first name initial and last name, which is the same initial as my name shortened.

If the name is completely wrong its a £15 fee to change at check-in.

Seems there's no official procedure so if there's a name mistake probably best to check with the operator before your trip.